# Генерация всех возможных комбинаций из 5 списков

Tags: python-3.x

Братцы помогите решить задачу на Python:

У меня есть 5 списков

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [11,12,13]
c = [21,22,23]
d = [31,32,33]
e = [41,42,43]
```

мне нужно получить из этих списков все возможные комбинации в таком приблизительно порядке

```
1,11,21,31,41 -----> 2,11,21,31,41 -----> 3,11,21,31,41
1,12,22,32,42 -----> 2,12,22,32,42 -----> 3,12,22,32,42
1,13,23,33,43 -----> 2,13,23,33,43 -----> 3,13,23,33,43
1,11,22,32,42 -----> 2,11,22,32,42 -----> 3,11,22,32,42
1,12,23,33,43 -----> 2,12,23,33,43 -----> 3,12,23,33,43
```

Обезательно чтобы все комбинации шли последовательно `a --> b --> c --> d --> e`

Пробывал данный метод но получаеться не то что нужно!!!

```
import itertools

a = [1,2,3,11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33,41,42,43]

for subset in itertools.combinations(a, 5):
    print(subset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
a = [1,2,3]
b = [11,12,13]
c = [21,22,23]
d = [31,32,33]
e = [41,42,43]
for subset in product(a, b, c, d, e):
     print(subset)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо друг огромное то что нужно)